# Centering an element in a responsive Design

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, center

I want to center an ad on my website. I tried using a div (Code Below). It centers properly on big screens, but when it comes to mobile devices, half of the ad is pushed out of the screen. Apologies if this has been asked before.

```
<div style="text-align: center;">
<div style="width: 640px; margin-top: 20px;">
 AD CODE COMES HERE</div>
</div>
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Try adding a max-width: 100% on the element so it never exceeds 100% of the width of the page.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Horizontally center a div in a div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/horizontally-center-a-div-in-a-div)

Answer (score 0):

Because you set fixed width of your AD div. Try set it in percentage like width:60%.

Answer (score 0):

Add `max-width` to the `ad` elemnt

```
<div style="text-align: center;">
<div style="width: 640px; margin-top: 20px;max-width:100%;">
 AD CODE COMES HERE</div>
</div>
```